# How can I create x number of textInput which are arranged vertically?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a dataset called `dat` and I can find the number of columns present by `x<-ncol(dat)`.

I want to create `x` number of textinputs which are shown vertically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example with `lapply` and `iris` dataset -

```
library(shiny)

dat <- iris
x<-names(dat)

ui <- fluidPage({
  uiOutput('textInput')
})

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$textInput <- renderUI({
    lapply(x, function(name) textInput(name, name))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]